# Assigning default values to columns

Tags: sqlalchemy

I've been trying to generate the following sql code for creating a MySQL column in a table using sqlalchemy:

```
`win` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

I am using this as my sqlalchemy statement:

```
class Matches(Base):
"""matches entity class"""
__tablename__ = 'matches'
__table_args__ = {
    'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
    'mysql_charset': 'utf8'
}
win = Column(TINYINT(1, unsigned=True), nullable=False, default=0)
```

This however does not generate the default value I want only the following:

```
win TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Also when I set default='CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' (in a different column) it automatically adds the on update which I don't want.
Am I missing something?

Also, just as a side question, how would I go about generating something like this using sqlalchemy:

```
UNIQUE KEY `matchid` (`match_id`)
```

I know that Column takes a unique bool attribute which will generate the UNIQUE part but when I use the Column attribute key='matchid' nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `server_default` and `unique` of [Column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column):

```
win = Column(TINYINT(1, unsigned=True), nullable=False, default=0, 
    server_default=text('0'),
    unique=True,
)
```